# Can I create wheels for python packages on macOS usable for a ubuntu docker image?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, python-wheel

I'm working on a python/django project. For deployment I want to create a ubuntu 16.04 docker image. When I'm working on a ubuntu local host, I generate all wheel files and they can be used to create image. ( I copy all of these wheels to docker, so I run `RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --no-index -f wheelhouse -r requirements.txt` in Dockerfile to install requirements using local wheels. where `wheelehouse` is a folder that I've copied all of my local wheels to it. )

But when I create wheels on macOS host, some generated wheels are something like `some_packagename-**macosx_10_6_intel**.whl` . So they're not usable to create an ubuntu docker image.

Is there a way I can force `pip wheel` to generate wheels for linux and not from source files on macOS?

Comment: how are you building wheels? do you use any compiled dependencies/extensions?

Comment: @Matthew I build wheels normally using `pip wheel`. for example `aiohttp` is one of packages that creates `*_maacosx.whl` kind of wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no C extensions, then you should be able to do:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
```

to get a non-platform specific `some_packagename-X.Y.Z-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

If you have C extensions, you need to generate platform specific wheels.

The best way to do this is by using Docker (which on MacOS runs in a virtual machine) and the [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) Docker containers to generate wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.7.

The generated wheels will install on many older versions of Linux, because of the way the `manylinux` containers are created. That is much better then starting your own Ubuntu XX.04 version (maybe in virtual machine) and not being able to install that on anything uses older compiler etc than your Ubuntu version does.